# regex for extracting string from ical data with possible linebreaks

Tags: ruby, regex, string, icalendar

I need to match some ical-data per regex to change the summary with the description values for each event and I'm somehow stuck there.

sample data set:

```
...
SUMMARY: Hello how are you doi
ng? Hope everything is fine?
DESCRIPTION: This is a description.
This: is still the description;
...
```

Linebreaks are intended. As are the ":" and ";" characters in the value.

I now need to extract the SUMMARY and the DESCRIPTION values.

My first try was something like this for:

```
summary = text.match /(?<=SUMMARY:).+(?=\n[A-Z]+:)/m
```

Here is a [link](http://rubular.com/r/DuvcWsV4AH) to the rubular example (without the lookbehind, seems rubular isn't able to do that)
It works for summary as expected but not for Description.

[Summary](http://rubular.com/r/DuvcWsV4AH)

[Description](http://rubular.com/r/aljNSTep3r)

Comment: You might want to read "[What's the best iCalendar (ics, ical) library in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285492/whats-the-best-icalendar-ics-ical-library-in-ruby)", rather than completely reinvent a wheel.

Comment: absolutely no idea why I didn't think of that

Comment: Because you, like 99.9% of the rest of us, were standing too close to the trees. We all do that.

Answer (score 0):

This works ok for me:

```
text = <<EOS
SUMMARY: Hello how are you doi
ng? Hope everything is fine?
DESCRIPTION: This is a description.
This: is still the description;
DATE: this gets selected too :(
EOS

summary = text.match /(?<=SUMMARY:)(?:.+?(?=[A-Z]+:)|.+?$)/m
p summary[0]
# " Hello how are you doi\nng? Hope everything is fine?\n"

description = text.match /(?<=DESCRIPTION:)(?:.+?(?=[A-Z]+:)|.+?$)/m
p description[0]
# " This is a description.\nThis: is still the description;"
```

Comment: Same thing as with stema. I can't assume that there isn't any other data coming after description.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you expect `\n[A-Z]+:` after the match because of your look ahead. But in your case the end of the string is following.

So the solution is to make an alternation expecting either the one or the other

```
DESCRIPTION:.+(?=\n[A-Z]+:|$)
```

See it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/LiEsSpp49b)

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I can't expect there to be an end (which is why I tried to include some "..." in the code above.
[rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/VKaBAEzmHO)

Comment: Because of that its an alternation, it stops matching either on `\n[A-Z]+:` OR on `$`. If there can be something else, you need to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Your example data does not conform to [RFC 5545, section 3.1 Content Lines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1):

> a long line can be split between any two characters by inserting a
> CRLF immediately followed by a single linear white-space character
> (i.e., SPACE or HTAB).

```
...
SUMMARY: Hello how are you doi
 ng? Hope everything is fine?
DESCRIPTION: This is a description.
    This: is still the description;
...
```

is a correct example.

> Unfolding is accomplished by removing the CRLF and the linear
> white-space character that immediately follows... parsing a content
> line, folded lines MUST first be unfolded

```
data = File.read("ical-data").gsub!(/\n[\s\t]/, '');
hash = Hash[data.scan(/^(SUMMARY|DESCRIPTION):(.+)/)];
puts "Description:", hash["DESCRIPTION"];
puts "Summary:", hash["SUMMARY"];
```